# Room Dao return type and Retrofit api return type not same (Need same return types for repository pattern)

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit, repository-pattern, android-room

API response:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "abcd",
   "sku": "2134",
   "name": "Blue Jeans",
   "price": {
    "current": 4.99,
    "original": 7.99,
    "currency": "EUR"
   },
   "brand": "Reebok",
   "image": "www.google.com",
   "published_at": "2015-09-22 17:43:12",
   "is_active": true
  },
  {
   "id": "efgh",
   "sku": "123",
   "name": "Black Jeans",
   "price": {
    "current": 6.99,
    "original": 8.99,
    "currency": "EUR"
   },
   "brand": "Nike",
   "image": "www.google.com",
   "published_at": "2015-09-02 10:35:07",
   "is_active": true
  }
 ]
}
```

Room Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ProductsDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM product")
    fun queryProducts(): Single<List<Product>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertProduct(product: Product)

}
```

API method:

```
@GET()
fun getProducts(@Url format: String): Observable<ProductsResponse>
```

ProductsResponse class:

```
data class ProductsResponse(
        val items: List<Product>
)
```

Now when I try to implement the repository pattern for an offline-first app, I need my room database and my API to return the same type of data. How can I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35000298/json-to-java-conversion-and-mapping-with-dao

Comment: The names mapping isn't really an issue. The issue is that my API call returns an Observable<ProductsResponse> but my DB call returns Observable<List<Product>>. When I implement the repository pattern, I need both my API and DB to return the same type.